# How to send one advanced special HTTP Request in JMeter to simulate a form submit to a C# Handler?

Tags: c#, jmeter, httprequest, httpcontext, handlers

I'm trying to send one HTTP request using JMeter, the problem is I don't know how to send the parameters.

I have my form in frontend in this way:

```
<form id="SampleForm" method="POST" action="MyHandler.ashx" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 ... 
 ....
 .....
</form>
```

I send this form to backend using: `$("#SampleForm").submit()`

And backend is built as following:

```
public class MyHandler: IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        ...
        ...
        ...
        var PartOfRequest = context.Request.Form["myFormElement"];
        ...
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem is in this part: ***context.Request.Form.*** I can send the HTTP Request to the handler, but it fails because it does not find the content of context.

Backend is waiting for one HTTP CONTEXT but I don´t know how I can sent a context from JMeter or if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to build the correct HTTP Request in JMeter is just recording it. There are several approaches like:

- [Using JMeter's own HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- [Using JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension)
- Using 3rd-party tool like [Badboy](http://www.badboy.com.au/)

---

If you need just a single request and consider recording the "overkill" - try the following changes in HTTP Request sampler

1. Change method to `POST`
2. Tick `Use multipart/form-data for POST`

[image: JMeter multipart post]

Answer (score 0):

Please share screenshot of your JMeter script. Without that I can only suggest recording the request with Fiddler to see how the parameters are sent.